# Are there any issues with using the windows os partition for shared data storage with Linux?

Tags: partition, dual-boot

My previous laptop had a 640Gb HDD and had partitioned it so that I had a separate NTFS partition for Data (documents, music, videos, etc) that I would access from both Linux and Windows in a dual-boot system.
My new SSD being much smaller (256Gb), so I was considering the possibility of keeping my data on the Windows partition to avoid:
1. Shrinking the Windows partition too much and end up having to repartition
2. Having "wasted" empty space on the Windows partition.
For similar reasons I was considering using the bare minimum amount of partitions for Linux (just root and swap).
My question is, would keeping my files on the Windows NTFS partition and accessing them through Linux be risky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issue,

(so long as you reboot properly without hybernate when switching, aka disabe "Fast Startup")

, just limitations

(no fancy lvmcache, btrfs snapshot diff backups, etc).

Comment: Hibernating instead of shutting down is _most definitely_ an issue, and one that is frequently asked about.